# Laravel join from two tables including null

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, mysql-workbench

I have 3 tables `listings, cities, state`.

`listings` table:

`id | city_id | state_id |...|`

Listing model:

```
class Listing extends Model{

function city(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\City');
}

function state(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\State');
}
```

Listing migration:

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id')->unsigned()->index()->unique()->autoIncrement();
        $table->integer('city_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('state_id')->nullable();
        ....
```

`city_id/state_id` is nullable !

`cities` table:

`id | state_id | name | ...|`

`City` Model:

```
class City extends Model{

    public function listings(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Listing');
    }

    function state(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\State');
    }
```

Migration:

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id')->unsigned()->index()->unique()->autoIncrement();
        $table->integer('state_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('name');
```

`states` table:

`id | name ...|`

Model:

```
class State extends Model{

    public function listings(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Listing');
    }

    function cities(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\City');
    }
```

Migration:

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('states', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id')->unsigned()->index()->unique()->autoIncrement();
        $table->string('name');
```

`listings` table has foreign keys to `state_id` and `city_id`. The relation for both is one city or state to many listings.

`city` table has foreign key `state_id`, too and relation one state to many cities.

I want to select everything from `states` and `cities` and count rows from listings table for each city/state, where I can:

```
foreach($listings as $listing){
    {{$listing->city or state . ' | ' . $listing->all (count listings for current city/state)}}
}
```

What I have tried is:

```
        $locations = DB::table('listings')
        ->join('states', 'states.id', '=', 'listings.state_id')
        ->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'listings.city_id')
        ->groupBy(['listings.city_id', 'listings.state_id' ])

        ->select(
                       'states.name.name as state',
                       'cities.name as city',
                       'states.id as state_id',
                       'city.id as city_id',
                       DB::raw("COUNT(listings.id) as countListings")
                   )->get();
```

The problem is that I want all cities and states in one collection with another key/property - count listings for that city/state.

Is it city or state, it doesn't matter, I just want their names with count listings.

I am using the latest Laravel version with MySQL.

Comment: do you used any eloquent relations?

Comment: Please replace this unclear structure description with CREATE TABLE stmts for all 3 tables, including indices and FKs.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it fully fits your needs, but if you'd like to avoid any complex SQL queries and unions, you can do following:

```
$states = State::with(['listings', 'listings_count'])->get();
$cities = City::with(['listings', 'listings_count'])->get();

$locations = $states->merge($cities);
```

It's not that good in terms of performance if your collections will be big, but still useful for smaller collections.